# Android Studio error - groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_8sqj**q9.android() is applicable for argument types: ***

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I prepared an android app in android studio then I copied my whole code manually from one sys to another. But after that, getting this error.
Below are my both gradle files and screenshot.(Not sure why manisfest file is not shown in android studio, this might be related)
Please dont mark copy as I have tried many solution from stackoverflow. those are same error but seems diff cause.

Module:app

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "dhritiapps.tulsiramayan"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 23
            versionName 5.0
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility 1.8
                targetCompatibility 1.8
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
        implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
        androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        implementation 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'
        implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
        implementation 'me.priyesh:chroma:1.0.2'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    }
```

Project

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    
            // NOTE: do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Answer (score 22):

Well, I just was confronted to a similar problem, and actually it's the feedback of Gradle that is really REALLY bad. It's failing because of some invalid declaration inside the "android" block.

In your case, it seems that it's only because of the value you assign to `versionName` not being inside (double) quotes as a string must be.

So, in your :app gradle file, just fix this:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        versionName '5.0'
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi i am facing this issue when i am addin proguard file kindly guide me what issue it is here is my proguard file  minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: @Adnanhaider I can't answer you without more information, but you should maybe create a new question as this could be related to something else. Like maybe a bad configuration inside your proguard file.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is that you might be using properties of some plugin inside android tag, which is not declared as plugin. In my case I was trying to use

```
firebaseCrashlytics {
                // If you don't need crash reporting for your debug build
                mappingFileUploadEnabled false
            }
```

without using below plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Just by adding plugin the issue is resolved.
Also please look for double quote and single quote string

Answer (score 1):

I got a message similar to mine today. The way I found to solve this error was by changing the version for the Gradle plugin on my build. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmbES.png)

I hope this could help you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Anything declared in the `android {}` block in your build.gradle could cause this build failure.

Additional to what the other answers have mentioned, look for any non-Gradle references.

For example, the cause of my build failure were these lines:

```
buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
installation {
    installOptions '-d', '-t'
    timeOutInMs '2 * 60 * 1000'
}
```

After removing them, the build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I ran

`flutter build apk --release -v`

and had

`WARNING` that `useProguard` DSL element is obsolete and should be removed. I had gradle 7.4.

When I removed `useProguard false` from `android/app/build.gradle`, all built smoothly.